# Why is GitLab sending notification emails to a different email address?

Tags: email, gitlab

GitLab sends notification emails to the email address I used during registration. **Can I change the target email address GitLab uses to send email notifications to?**

I've already tried setting/changing my email address on my "Profile settings" but it's used only for display; it doesn't change where GitLab sends notification emails to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it seems I figured out the causing issue.

As it turns out the "Email" property on my "Profile settings" *does* specify where GitLab sends notification emails. The problem was a bit more elaborate.

**There were two GitLab accounts that had the same username!** Both belonged to me; one was a regular user and the other was an admin. The two users had different email addresses; just their usernames were the same.

This caused some kind of an anomaly; even though an action was triggered for the *admin* user the notification email went to the email address of my other user; strange indeed.

I changed the username of one of my users to make them unique. After that, everything worked well.

Hope this will help someone in the future.